# cookie directive EU message. How to save choice?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know, there are a tone of 3th party solutions to comply with the cookie EU directive. But I want to learn how to do it myself. I want the following: when a user clicks on "Accept", the choice is remembered for the whole browsing session. Currently the message shows up everytime the page is refreshed. Thanks,

```js
//shows cookie message
$(document).ready(function(){
      
      $(".cookie").toggleClass("cookieDisplayed");
      
      //hides cookie message
      $(".acceptCookies").on("click", function(){
        $(".cookie").removeClass("cookieDisplayed");
        
      });
  });
```

```css
.cookie {
  padding:20px;
  font-size:80%;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background:#F55D2D;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  top:-150px;
  
  transition: top 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: top 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: top 1.5s;
}

.cookie button{
  margin-left:20px;
  position:relative;
  left:100px;
  background:white;
  color:#F55D2D;
  border: 0;
  border-radius:4px;
}

.cookie button:hover {
  background:#F89576;
  color:white;
}

.cookie button a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#F55D2D;
}

.cookie.cookieDisplayed {
  
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </header>
  <body>
     <div class="cookie">
       <p>We are using cookies to give you the best experience on our site. Cookies are files stored in your browser and are used by most websites to help personalise your web experience.</p>
       <p>By continuing to use our website without changing the settings, you are     agreeing to our use of cookies.</p>
       <button><a href="aboutus.html">More information</a></button>
       <button class="acceptCookies">Accept</button>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript changes to the element will not persist across reloads

The best way to handle the situation is, ironically, with a cookie.

Sorry: I'm getting too cute with my "it takes a cookie to acknowledge a cookie."

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is the correct answer. Conceptually (and legally in the eu) cookies and localStorage are similar. Both store a value on the user's machine--that they accepted the cookie notice in this case--and both persist even if the user shuts down the browser.

There are differences between the two. Cookies are from an earlier age of the Internet and nowadays are for talking the server. localStorage is better for talking to the client. Either could be made to work in this case (but local storage will be easier).

sessionStorage only persists until the user shuts down the browser.

Comment: Thanks @crowhill. Someone commented this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage Do you think this approach would work?

Comment: @perettxintxola sessionStorage only stores the information for the current session before it is deleted automatically.  localStorage is a better option for long-term storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).